# How to include 2 class file in a php file

Tags: php

I'm trying to include two php class file in my index file. But console returns the following error:

```
Cannot declare class Experience, because the name is already in use
 in C:\Users\p-pri\wa\php_oop\es_freetime\experience.php on line 3
```

This is how I've included files in index.php:

```
     <?php  

    include("./sport.php");
    include("./relax.php");
```

Line 3 of experience.php

```
    class Experience {
    #restofmycode
```

What's wrong?

Comment: This doesn't look like [mcve]

Comment: Could you please show more code as @Dharman  mentioned

Comment: Added below this comment

Comment: You should use [`include_once`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php). Or, even better, use an autoloader.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are importing that class file in multiple places. This causes it to be loaded twice.

To avoid this kind of problem, you can use [`require_once`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) instead of your `include` calls. The syntax is the same:

```
require_once "./experience.php";
```

This will make php load this file just on first call. The. Other calls will be ignored, but the class will be available.

As suggested in comments, you can also use a autoloader to make things easier and simpler. See this article: https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/php-composer-the-autoloader-d676a2f103aa

Comment: My bad. Like 7 years i don't import/require a file manually! :-)

Comment: I added require_once in index.php but console return me this error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Sport' not found in C:\Users\p-pri\wa\eserci
tazione_php_oop\es_freetime\index.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\p-pri\wa\esercitazione_php_oop\es_freetime\index.php on lin
e 11